# SFDX packaging - Report folder sharing settings

Tags: salesforcedx, package, 2gp, reports-folder

I am running into an issue while trying to install an unmanaged package / deploying metadata through SFDX.

On the ORG I am working on we have Report Folders which should be initially shared with some specific roles. Please find an example of one of those report folders metadata file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>Role1</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Role</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>Role2</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Role</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>Role3</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Role</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>My Report Folder</name>
</ReportFolder>
```

However, when installing a package with this metadata included the report folder is created but no permissions are applied, even though Role1, Role2 and Role3 exist (and are part of the package as well).

Additionally, deploying this file through `sfdx:force:source:deploy` works as expected (the sharing settings are applied). Has anyone faced this issue in the past? Is it a known issue / not possible at the time?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't package "shares" that way. While it makes sense in a general way, imagine if ISVs could package shares like that? It could cause unintentional chaos. That said, I can't seem to find it in the docs either way.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox! Thank you for your answer :) I can understand that it can make sense that these cannot be packaged for the reasons you explained. But then why would it work with the sfdx:force:source:deploy command? Shouldn't it keep the behavior and do not apply any changes?

Comment: Packages and metadata deployments are two different things. It's one thing for an ISV to distribute code, quite another for a customer that wants to move changes from a Sandbox to Production. Again, unfortunately, I don't know where to find this in the documentation, so I'm not sure what else to say. Have you tried contacting support?

Comment: No, not really @sfdcfox. But will do and post some updates once I have them. Again: thanks for your help! :)