# Deploying shared EmailFolder with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, email-template

I have an Email Folder I want to deploy with sfdx to another org. I did all of the configs in SF and pulled everything.
I tried it with

```
sfdx force source deploy -p app/default/email/test.emailFolder-meta.xml
```

and this is the xml File itself

```
<EmailTemplateFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <folderShares>
        <accessLevel>Manage</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>myRole</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>RoleAndSubordinatesInternal</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
    <name>test Templates</name>
</EmailTemplateFolder>
```

I get no error message and the folder appears in the destination org, however the Rolesharing information is gone. All of the metadata is already there, including the role as well.
I assume that it is required to include in the same deployment also some other metadata, but I find no info on which exact one.

I tried pulling it from the destination org, and this is how the folder looks there.

```
<EmailTemplateFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <name>test Templates</name>
</EmailTemplateFolder>
```

Comment: I had the same issue on sharing on reports. The sharing has to be post deployment manual step.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/sfdx-packaging-report-folder-sharing-settings